# Is there any way in SQL Server Management Studio to script a stored procedure using if-exists/drop/create/alter?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I script a stored procedure as drop/create I get something like this:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
...
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

However what i want to see is this:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
...
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure] AS' 
END
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

Is there any way to get SQL Server to script it this way, or do I need to edit the procedure definition manually after scripting it?

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? Surely if the stored procedure has just been dropped there's no need to check if it still exists.

Comment: That `IF NOT EXISTS` isn't needed - the previous line already deleted the stored procedure. What you ask for isn't useful. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. If you want to alter a procedure then why not just alter it? Your snippet is not DROP/CREATE. It is a strange DROP/CREATE (with dynamic sql)/ALTER. Why bother dropping it, then creating it just like it was only to then alter it?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2016 or later and SSMS 18 then there's a script as 'CREATE or ALTER' option.

Comment: In any case, that script is generated by SSMS, a standalone client tool, not SQL Server. Other tools create different scripts. *All* of them create scripts based on templates. If you want to create your own scripts you can do so, eg with the [SMO library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I bet MS can not cover all kinds of requirement basis snippets. You can create your own snippets and use..

Comment: Honestly I don't know why we do it this way, it doesn't make much sense to me either...

Comment: How do I create my own snippets?